# Chosing the right HTML5 canvas library for my project

Tags: canvas, kineticjs, fabricjs, easeljs

I need some advice here because I'm really afraid of choices and it's very confusing to me.
So, it's about choosing a canvas utility for my project. I made up my mind to only focus on three of the most known: EaselJS, FabricJS and KineticJS. 
The project is not a game; It's a website (mvc5) where, among other things, I'm going to make a 'Home Designer' but only for electric devices and sensors (I'm in the domotic field). Obviously, the major parts are setting the plan, dragging and dropping, linking every sensor to its device, saving, etc.
I thought about Easel, I could use SoundJS too. FabricJS has a good documentation... I'm confused.

Comment: Take a look at canvas libraries comparison table — https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aqj_mVmuz3Y8dHNhUVFDYlRaaXlyX0xYSTVnalV5ZlE#gid=0

Comment: Use EaselJS and the rest of the CreateJS suite, because its great and so are the people who work on it.  People like me. =)
SoundJS will work regardless of which library you choose, but obviously has syntax in common with the rest of the CreateJS libraries (EaselJS, TweenJS, and PreloadJS).

Comment: @OJay can you please provide me with an example of drag and drop of multiple images, using EaselJS library, except from the one of the Daisies? It's not constructive, I need a more complex demo. My app (the home designer) is about dragging from an accordion, onto a canvas element.

Comment: @Sahar I am not more helpful than what you would find on the [EaselJS site](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS).  Maybe checkout the official tutorials?  I'm not sure if you can drag from one dom element (accordion) to another (canvas), but if your accordion is implemented in the same canvas element it should be straight forward.
Hope that helps.

Comment: I can't implement an accordion in canvas. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I chose to use KineticJS for personal purposes, just because I didn't find it easy to use EaselJS (after trying of course). KineticJS is more flexible as a library, and there's more labs and tutorials, in addition to the amount of things I found in SO.

Choices are always based on **personal** opinions. Just leaving this answer for future users.